# how do I pass a parameter to a javaScript function which comes from the BasePage of my web page, on a click button event?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I have this button click event:

```
$('#btnDelete').on('click', function(userId)
{
    var treeView = $("#treeview").data("kendoTreeView");

    $('#treeview').find('input:checkbox:checked').each(function()
    {
        var li = $(this).closest(".k-item")[0];
        var notificationId = treeView.dataSource.getByUid(li.getAttribute('data-uid')).ID;
        $.ajax(
            {
                url: '../api/notifications/deleteNotification?userId=' + userId + '&notificationId=' + notificationId,
                type: 'DELETE',
                success: alert('Delete successful.'),
                failure: alert('Delete failed.')
            });
    });
});
```

The "userId" comes from the base page:

```
public class BasePage : System.Web.UI.Page, IRequiresSessionState
{
    public int UserId
    {
        get
        {
            return T2Identity.UserId;
        }
    }
}
```

How do I, on the click event of the button "btnDelete," pass the userId variable to my JavaScript function?

Comment: You have to render this value (or better yet and encrypted version of it) into the HTML of the pages or store it in a cookie you send to the page.

Comment: I would suggest not passing the value, but instead changing `api/notifications/deleteNotification` to read the value from `T2Identity.UserId` in the same way your `BasePage` does.

Comment: @JasonP, how would I read T2Identity.UserId from the java script file?

Comment: `/api/notifications/deleteNotification` is a javascript file? I assumed it was a Web API controller.

Comment: its a web api call. and my bad, i just understood what you said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way I can think of, is to either pass the `UserId` property as cookie inside the HtmlResponse that's returned when the page is first sent.

Another way, is to pass it inside an Asp.NET tag on the page load. Just add this inside the 'body' of the page:

```
<input type="hidden" id="user_id" name="user_id" value="<%= base.UserId.ToString() %>" />
```

Answer (score 0):

The only objects that can be passed to the function are the event (in your case a click) and the element that triggered the event (in your case the button).

Everything else must be passed as a global variable, or attached to the above objects. For example you could set userId as an attribute of your button.

Answer (score 0):

you can always create a hidden field and pass it to your page and then read the value.

or if you want to call it from the webmethod

```
   [WebMethod]
    public string GetUserId()
    {
          return UserId.ToString();
    }
```

and javascript

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function HandleIT() {
            PageMethods.GetUserId(); 
            function onSucess(result) {
                alert(result);
            }
            function onError(result) {
                alert('Something wrong.');
            }
        }
    </script>
```